# Starting redis-server process within PHP script

Tags: php, shell, unix, redis, shell-exec

In a PHP script, I periodically check to see if my redis-server is running, using `redis-cli ping`.

If this returns `NULL`, I want to restart the redis-server within that same script, and ping redis again.

What is the best way to do this?

The closest I've come is using `shell_exec("redis-server")` but that makes the PHP script hang (since it starts the screen in that same process). Is there a way I can run `screen redis-server` within PHP without hanging up the current script?

I've also tried `exec("sh " . __DIR__ . "/start_redis.sh")` which contains `screen redis-server`, but that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is not running as a daemon, hence it is hanging. Check out:

http://www.art-coder.com/2011/12/01/how-to-run-redis-server-as-daemon/

Once you set it up as a daemon, the shell_exec() call should return immediately.

You should also ensure that the php script is running as the same effective user as the redis-server